Is there a [solution] to this problem?
The solution tag refers to an application organizing structure in Visual Studio. From its excerpt:

A solution (.sln file) is a structure for organizing projects in Visual Studio. It groups one or more projects that work together to create an application.

However, the name "solution" is really ambiguous. It could easily be a number of things, including a meta tag for any question looking for a solution (read: all of them). Most recently, it was used as the sole tag in this question, which has nothing to do with Visual Studio at all. Could we rename it to visual-studio-solution or similar for clarity?
Note: projects-and-solutions seems to cover similar subject matter. I'm hesitant to request a tag synonym though; there are at least a couple other IDEs that have a similar concept, so having a Visual Studio-specific tag seems fine.

There are currently 666(!) questions using the tag. Why is it causing problems? Is anyone actually searching for questions based on this tag? To me it seems like a more or less useless tag to hang on another tag just for the heck of it.

@Lundin See VLAZ’s answer - it refers to a pretty specific configuration that people do have actual questions about. It’s worth keeping, it just needs a new name.

I appreciate the restraint in not going for a different play on words…

couldn't agree more @Anerdw .  Why all making this so complex?  It's a ubiquitous thing that there will be a tag like "Music" (which is Apple's utterly idiotic name for their mp4 player thing) and this forum will, obviously, just change it to "Mac-OS-Music-App" or "Apple-Music-App" or such.

A "solution" is a Microsoft term more specific than just a project. There are some solution-level problems you can have or solution-based queries you can have for how to configure your project. Moreover, for most other technology stacks "project" is just an abstract term to refer to "the thing where the code is". It is not well-defined. Solutions are very concrete things described by an .sln (read "solution") file.
So, it is not a synonym for project. In fact, I would suggest project is probably not useful but I have not examined if it really brings any benefit. solution does.
In the past, I went through questions tagged solution (but that did not have a Microsoft technology tag) and removed it where it was not appropriate. I still monitor for new questions that popup. The custom filter I have uses the following query:
[solution] -[c#] -[.net] -[visual-studio] -[nuget] -[visual-studio-code] -[visual-studio-2010] -[visual-studio-2012] -[visual-studio-2015] -[visual-studio-2013] -[visual-studio-2008] -[visual-studio-2017] -[visual-studio-2019] -[visual-studio-2022] -[visual-studio-2005] -[visual-studio-debugging] -[visual-studio-extensions] -[visual-studio-cordova] -[visual-studio-lightswitch] -[visual-studio-mac] -[visual-studio-app-center] -[visual-studio-express] -[visual-studio-addins] -[visual-studio-2003] -[asp.net] -[msbuild] -[csproj] -[sharepoint] -[vb.net] -[ssis] -[dynamics-crm] -[dynamics-crm-2011] -[dynamics-crm-2013] -[dynamics-365] -[dynamics-ax-2012] -[dynamics-crm-online] -[dynamics-crm-2016] -[dynamics-crm-4] -[dynamics-ax-2009] -[dynamics-crm-2015] -[dynamics-crm-365] -[dynamics-nav] -[dynamics-business-central] -[dynamics-365-operations] -[dynamics-ax-2012-r2] -[dynamics-crm-webapi] -[dynamics-ax-2012-r3] -[dynamics-gp] -[dynamics-al] -[dynamics-crm-portals] -[.net] -[.net-core] -[.net-4.0] -[.net-6.0] -[.net-3.5] -[.net-4.5] -[.net-assembly] -[.net-5] -[.net-2.0] -[.net-8.0] -[.net-standard] -[.net-7.0] -[.net-4.8] -[.net-framework-version] -[.net-core-3.1] -[.net-standard-2.0] -[.net-core-3.0] -[maui] -[.net-4.6] -[.net-1.1] -[monodevelop] -[tfs] -[xamarin-studio]

It is not Microsoft-specific, there's plenty of other programming IDEs except VS that use the term "solution" meaning project.

@Lundin I'm saying that "solution" as a project is used by Microsoft and the tag is very explicitly for that. There are also other project-like things that Microsoft calls "solution" - for example, whatever Dynamics is has solutions, as does Sharepoint. If one wants to fix their project setup in a MS-related tech, then "solution" is a lot more concrete than using more generic terms.

Both shouldn't exists. If the question is about the sln file, it should have the Visual Studio tag (if the file is expected to be consumed by visual studio), for everything else there's specific tags for each ide.

Propose rename to:
visual-studio-solution

Wouldn't you just rename the tag from [solution] to

[Visual-Studio-sln]

or

[Visual-Studio-sln-file]

or

[VS-sln-file]

or

[sln]

how easy is that?
(Sure, there might be cases where someone has accidentally used teh extant tag for "Blackberry OS modem Solution Widget API" or something, but, that sort of misuse is true of 100.0% of tags - so what?)

I like [tag:visual-studio-solution] because it uses the full name (not the extension) while still following the convention from tags like [tag:visual-studio-debugging] and [tag:visual-studio-lightswitch].

Great, let's do that

Yes. Remove the solution and the project tag. both are incredibly ambiguous and have a better tag: visual-studio. Since both tags are intrinsically linked to Visual Studio, a question about a sln file is obviously about visual studio. Same with project, each IDE could manage and have different functions and methods to manage projects. Questions about the later only have an abstract relationship, that IDE's decided to use the same word about to describe a collection of files that share a goal.

We have a tag called [tag:stdvector], even though a question about a std::vector is obviously a question about [tag:c++]. A [tag:visual-studio-solution] tag seems reasonable to me.

The solution files can be consumed by tools other than Visual Studio. Most notably, MSBuild is a utility that can build or run projects stand-alone (VS uses it). But solution files can also be generated outside of VS. It is a specific enough technology and there can be questions about it by itself.

I do suspect [[tag:project]] is not really useful, though. Neither by itself or in combination with other tags.

@VLAZ would something like [tag:microsoft-solution] be better perhaps?

@DavidConrad I honestly can't tell. The tag is paired with stuff like Dynamics and Sharepoint and TFS and I don't know if that doesn't refer to something else. It might be a completely different way of organising projects than the solution files used in C# or others Dynamics CRM, I believe is a web platform, for example, so a "solution" there might be a web UI thing.

@Fattie sounds like you're disputing something other than what I was talking about. [visual-studio] is not a good name for the tag. Which you seem to agree with yet phrased it as if you disagreed with my statement.

@VLAZ I think [visual-studio-solution] is fine. The Microsoft docs specifically say, "A solution is a structure for organizing projects in Visual Studio." SLN files may be used for other things, but they are ultimately a Visual Studio concept.

@VLAZ same reasoning. It's used for multiple consumers, the consumer tag should be used instead. There's no reason to have a tag for something which behavior and functions are dependent on the context aka: ambiguous.

@Anerdw bad tags existing shouldn't be used to create more bad tags. Each tag should demonstrate its value on its own. A counter example would be the Sony tag, which exists because it proven useful at that time. If at later date it proves to be too much, we can remove it. Are you saying that this is an exception? Why?

It's not a bad tag. It just has a bad name. A solution in the Visual Studio sense is a specific technology that someone could have an actual programming question is about. The tag currently has >650 questions, even after VLAZ's filtering; deleting the tag entirely would remove information from all of those questions.

Tags are their names @Anerdw . You can't say that a tag is "good" if their only quality is their name. Number of questions is irrelevant, internet had way more questions than that and was removed. So, what value does it bring other than existing?

Let me clarify. The tag in its current form is bad. A tag that refers to the VS concept of a solution is good. In other words, the tag should be renamed, not deleted wholesale. I’m not going to rehash why a VS solution tag is good; that’s been covered in enough answers and comments.
